Equation for the development of an oblique cone in polar coordinates
The development of a right cone is a circular sector that's fairly easy to describe mathematically. The development of an oblique cone, however, has a different shape (as one can find on Google Image):

In general, in polar coordinates, it's a generic function $r(\theta)$ with $0<\theta<\theta_{max}$

My question is: what is the equation of the development of an oblique cone in polar coordinates?
I know that I'm supposed to show my approach at computing it but before I try, I wonder if anyone else has already done it before me. I've searched online and I'm quite surprised by the lack of information on the matter. But I might have simply missed it, since my access to mathematics literature is limited (mostly Google and some old books).
Does anyone know?

So I gave it a go and guess I can (almost) answer my own question. My math is based on the following figure:

where:

$d$ is the distance from the projection of the vertex on the base to the center of the base
$h$ is the height of the cone
$\alpha$ is the angle around the center
I assume that the radius of the base is equal to $1$
$r$ and $\theta$ are what I'm looking for

What I'm interested in is a function $r=f(\theta)$ that relates $r$ and $\theta$. The key part is the small right triangle that's highlighted in the figure above, inside the circle. Simple trigonometry on that triangle gives us the equation we must solve:
$$d\alpha=rd\theta\cdot\mathrm{sin}(\beta)\tag{1}$$
It's easy to show from the geometry of the cone that $r$ is equal to:
$$r=\sqrt{h^2+d^2+1-2d\cos{\alpha}}\tag{2}$$
In order to find $\beta$, we can can compute the unit vectors $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{t}$:
$$\hat{r}=\frac{1}{||r||}(d-\cos{\alpha},\sin{\alpha}, h)$$
$$\hat{t}=(\sin{\alpha}, \cos{\alpha}, 0)$$
It follows that:
$$\cos{\beta}=\hat{r}\cdot\hat{t}=\frac{d\sin{\alpha}}{r}=\frac{d\sin{\alpha}}{\sqrt{h^2+d^2+1-2d\cos{\alpha}}}$$
hence:
$$\sin{\beta}=\sqrt{1-\cos{\beta}^2}=\frac{\sqrt{h^2+d^2\cos{\alpha}^2+1-2d\cos{\alpha}}}{r}=\sqrt{\frac{h^2+d^2\cos{\alpha}^2+1-2d\cos{\alpha}}{h^2+d^2+1-2d\cos{\theta}}}\tag{3}$$
$\beta$ is always between $0$ and $\pi$, so we can use the positive sign for the square root. If we now replace (2) and (3) into (1) and rearrange things we get:
$$d\theta=\frac{\sqrt{h^2+1-2d\cos{\alpha}+d^2\cos{\alpha}^2}}{h^2+1-2d\cos{\alpha}+d^2}d\alpha\tag{4}$$
This can be integrated only from $0$ to $\pi$ since the rest is symmetric.
The problem is that this integral is very hard to solve (at least it is for me). I tried to feed it to wolframalpha but all I got was a funny mess. I may ask a separate question just for that.
Equation (4), if solved, gives an expression for $\theta$ as a function of $\alpha$. We would then have to replace it in equation (2) to get what we're looking for. Or even better, we can express the solution in parametric form as:
$$(r(\alpha), \theta(\alpha))$$

I'm (slowly) working on a close form for equation (4) but in the meantime I tried to solve it numerically with a computer. Here's a few results with different values of $d$ and $h$. I also tried to create paper models out of them and they work as expected!




